# Turn numerical filter into ON/OFF

Tags: views, 6

I'm using [uc_best_sellers](http://www.ubercart.org/node/10863) to count the number of times a product has been sold.

The module provides a numeric views filter like this:

[image: screenshot #1]

I'd like to have a view like this:

[image: screenshot #2]

A product would be a best seller if it was sold more than 50 times (in my case).

What would I need to achieve this filtering style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using exposed filters for this, I think it will be easier to make separate views displays with overridden filters. Then either use quicktabs to display the different filter options, or make each one a page display with a path and output the links to the filter displays in the headers.

Comment: Because it says 'filter' doesn't mean that it's an exposed filter, so, yes, Jody, is correct that you need three different views. You can use QuickTabs which are nice or create three different secondary tabs.